# Kotlin: try catch in CoroutineScope still crash the app

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using the code below for a network request throught okhttp3:

```kotlin
runOnDefaultDispatcher {
                try {
                    val newsResponse = Xxxx.xxxxClient.getNews()
                    if (newsResponse.success && newsResponse.data != null && newsResponse.data.count() > 0) {
                        runOnMainDispatcher {
                            val adapter = NewsAdapter(newsResponse.data, getString(R.string.news)).also {
                                initListener(it, newsResponse.data)
                            }
                            binding.list.adapter = adapter
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    }
                } catch (exception: Exception) {
                    runOnMainDispatcher {
                        binding.list.visibility = View.GONE

                        val errorLayout = view.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.error_layout)
                        errorLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        errorLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_title).text = "Oops..."
                        errorLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.error_message).text = exception.message
                    }
                }
            }
```

The implementation code of `runOnDefaultDispatcher` and `runOnMainDispatcher` is down below:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun block(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit {
    return block
}

fun runOnDefaultDispatcher(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) =
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default, block = block)

suspend fun <T> onDefaultDispatcher(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T) =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default, block = block)

fun runOnIoDispatcher(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) =
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO, block = block)

suspend fun <T> onIoDispatcher(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T) =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO, block = block)

fun runOnMainDispatcher(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) =
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate, block = block)

suspend fun <T> onMainDispatcher(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T) =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate, block = block)
```

I except the exception would be caught and no crash would appear.
However the application still **CRASH**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Comment: You should scope your coroutines with the lifecycle of your app. Don't use `GlobalScope`. Also, you must use a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` when using launch, because you have already left the try-catch when the exception is thrown. Read more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#exception-propagation

Comment: I have moved those code to GlobalScope.async and wrap with runBlocking, I don't know if it is the correct method or it will block the UI interface. However the exception was caught, thank you for helping

Comment: Just stop using `GlobalScope` at all. It's no wonder you get these surprises when using it.

Answer (score 0):

The calls to `launch` don't work well with `try/catch`.

e.g. this will crash the app

```
try {
    GlobalScope.launch { throw Excepton() }
} catch (e: Exception) {
}
```

On the other hand, `suspend` functions work with `try/catch` as you would expect so this example DOES NOT crash the app:

```
suspend fun bang(): Unit = throw Exception()

try {
    bang()
} catch (e: Exception) {
}
```

In your code you have `launch` inside `try/catch`, meaning you have a scenario like the first example here.

The solution is to build your program as suspend functions, and only use `launch` one to execute the result (note: this doesn't apply universally but does apply in this scenario).

When running the program you probably want to use `lifecycleScope`.

Also you might want to consider using a `ViewModel` so that the network call survives configuration changes.

You can check the [Kotlin Coroutines on Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) guide for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference between to code blocks. The first one will crash because exception occurs in a different thread. The second one will not crash because you are catching exception in the right place.

```
fun main() {

    val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Default)

    //First way
    try {
        scope.launch {
            exceptionThrowingFunction()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println(e.message)
    }
    //Second way
    scope.launch {
        try {
            exceptionThrowingFunction()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message)
        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(10000)
}

private suspend fun exceptionThrowingFunction() {
    delay(10)
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Test Error")
}
```